# Why does UISearchDisplayController has to be a class variable?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm using Xamarin iOS.

In `ViewDidLoad` I'm instantiating my `UISearchBar`, `UISearchDisplayController`, `UISearchDisplayDelegate` and `UITableViewSource`. Thereby I'm using a class variable for the `UISearchDisplayController`. Because I only used it in `ViewDidLoad` I moved the class variable for `UISearchDisplayController` to a local variable.

Now the strange things happened:

- The search didn't worked anymore. Regardless of my input nothing changed.
- Also the searchbar didn't moved to the navigation bar as it is the standard behavior.

Now I reverted my changes back and it works again. I checked my code and there is nothing different than this.

But why can I use `UISearchDisplayController` only as class variable?

**Edit:**

@class variable:

```
namespace MyApp
{
    partial class MyTableListController : UITableViewController
    {
        // class variable
        private UISearchDisplayController searchController;

        public MyTableListController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
            // do some init
        }

        #region View lifecycle

        public override void ViewDidLoad (){
            // ..
        }
    }
}
```

Seems that the controller is not only used in `ViewDidLoad` and therefore must be available in the whole class (e.g. class variable).

Comment: What exactly is a `class variable` ? Post code to be clear. In some languages it means a static field.

Comment: Your _class variable_ is officially called a _field_ in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make the search controller a method variable, the garbage collector is free to collect it once the method finishes.

You must ensure you keep a reference to the search controller as long as it's in use.

Comment: This cannot be the whole answer.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I don't think I follow. What are you missing?

Comment: Maybe that controller is a special xamarin thingy but normally you wouldn't be able to use it (search) w/o keeping a reference.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, that's exactly the problem of the reporter was having, it wasn't working when he wasn't keeping a reference.